# Firebase onChildAdded returns null data and then onChildChanged after updating child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do some basic Firebase operations however, the childEventListener is not behaving as expected.

I have a list of restaurant orders which I display in a list using a Firebase query and ChildEventListener. The query is used to get all orders that are un-cooked i.e WHERE cooked = false.

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(UUID + "/" + outletID + "/orders");
Query query = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("cooked").equalTo(false);

mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.e(TAG, "ChildEventListener() - onChildAdded - " + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
            mAdapter.addOrder(order);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.e(TAG, "ChildEventListener() - onChildChanged - " + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
            mAdapter.updateOrder(order);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e(TAG, "ChildEventListener() - onChildRemoved - " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + ", exist - " + dataSnapshot.exists());

            Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
            mAdapter.removeOrder(order);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.e(TAG, "ChildEventListener() - onChildMoved - " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.w(TAG, "ChildEventListener : onCancelled - ", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };

    query.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

This works fine and it pulls the right data out.

I have another list which gets all the orders that are cooked i.e WHERE cooked = true. I use a one time event listener for this and shows the correct data as expected.

```
Query query = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("cooked").equalTo(true);
```

In my list of cooked orders, when user taps on a order, it is meant to update the cooked flag back to "false" and appear in the list of un-cooked orders. It is done using the following setValue() method.

```
mDatabaseReference.child(order.getPushID()).child("cooked").setValue(false);
```

**Issue 1**

When I load the activity and there are no un-cooked orders, this is where the problem occurs. As I tap on a cooked order, the Firebase database updates the cooked flag as expected however, the onChildAdded() is called as expected but the order object data is null. I also get onChildChanged call after that with the order object data.

When I carry on tapping cooked orders, it calls onChildAdded() once with correct data as expected. So technically, I am missing the first order that was cooked due to the null data.

If I load the activity that has 1 or more un-cooked orders and I tap on a cooked order, the onChildAdded() gets called as expected and updates the list of un-cooked orders.

I tried changing the setValue() to updateChildren() but still same outcome.

Comment: I have been experiencing a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808339/setvalue-for-firebase-data-update-causes-other-fields-in-updated-object-to-ret

Answer (score 3):

Usually, such an issue is reproduced with Firebase when you write several properties of one object using several setValue operations. I suggest a following scenario:

1. Order is added to `\orders`, `onChildAdded` is called, but this is empty because of its `cooked` property is `false`.
2. `Cooked` property is set to `false`. `onChildUpdated` is called with order you need.

Maybe this is not what you do, but just how it's implemented under the hood. Maybe you could just use `onChildUpdated`?

Comment: I guess I can do something in onChildChanged but I don't get why onChildAdded doesn't have my data when it should because the listener is looking out for un-cooked orders. Subsequent setValue() calls work as expected but not first time when there are no un-cooked orders.

Comment: Just because first time query handling is implemented differently in Firebase SDK.