# setValue() for Firebase data update causes other fields in updated object to return null in onChildAdded in childEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener, children

I have a list of Firebase message objects, each of which may be updated before an activity is opened, at which point a Firebase `ChildEventListener()` fires off (children are handled in `onChildAdded()`).

The update uses a `setValue()` on the `status` field:

```
database.getReference("Messages").child(roomID).child(msgID).child("status").setValue("delivered");
```

[image]

The `ChildEventListener()` fires off fine for all children when the activity is opened. However, for those children (messages) that had their status' updated before hand, they return `null` for all fields except the `status` field.
In the Firebase database, all fields are as they should be (non-null), so there is nothing wrong with the data. 
Upon exiting the activity and re-entering, all children are returned in the `ChildEventListener()` as they should be (no more null data returned).

In short, two `ChildEventListener()` calls are required to return all the data for a child after a `setValue()` is run on that child.

More code and context can be provided if required. Let me know.

**Edit 1:** here is the listener: (it is in `onResume()`)

```
newMessageListner = myMessageRoomRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                    String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Message messageClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    String messageUserID = messageClass.getUserId();

                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Key: " + messageKey);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Status: " + messageClass.getStatus());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message User ID: " + messageUserID);

}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**Edit 2:** I call the `getValue()` from `sendNotification()` in my `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
   private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, StudentChatActivity.class);
        String clickAction = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
        Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        String roomID = remoteMessage.getData().get("ROOMID");
        String origin = remoteMessage.getData().get("ORIGIN");
        String msgID = remoteMessage.getData().get("MSGID");
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload, roomID: " + roomID);

        database.getReference("Messages").child(roomID).child(msgID).child("status").setValue("delivered");

        intent.putExtra("ROOMID", roomID);
        intent.putExtra("USERID", UserID);
        intent.putExtra("USERNAME", UserName);
        intent.putExtra("ORIGIN", origin);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.received_message);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_pickle)
                        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                        .setPriority(1)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: can you post ChildEventListener code !

Comment: @kdblue Included.

Comment: where do you use setValue()?

Comment: It's used in my `FirebaseMessagingService`. Irrespective of how I get to the activity containing the `ChildEventListener()`, the issue occurs.

Comment: More specifically, in the `onMessageReceived()`

Comment: please post your code where do you set the setValue() !

Comment: My mistake, it is set in the `sendNotification()` method in the `FirebaseMessagingService`. See Edit 2.